# Unity build report for Android is missing information

Tags: unity

This is my build report for Android:

```
Build Report
Uncompressed usage by category:
Textures      3.4 mb     3.7% 
Meshes        0.0 kb     0.0% 
Animations    0.0 kb     0.0% 
Sounds        0.0 kb     0.0% 
Shaders       0.0 kb     0.0% 
Other Assets  13.5 kb    0.0% 
Levels        21.9 kb    0.0% 
Scripts       687.9 kb   0.7% 
Included DLLs 3.9 mb     4.3% 
File headers  13.2 kb    0.0% 
Complete size 92.5 mb    100.0%
```

The space used by all the categories does not add up to the complete size of 92.5 mb. The build report in the [Unity manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ReducingFilesize.html) shows full utilisation by the listed categories. Where does the other 91% of the utilisation go?

Comment: are you sure you don't have anything in streaming assets folder or other unity folders?

Comment: I have a prefabs, scenes, scripts, and sprites folders. Nothing else.